# Using a ThreadPool with a Delegate?

Tags: c#, multithreading, delegates, threadpool

I'm attempting to use the `QueueUserWorkItem` method on `ThreadPool`, however, I'm having some problems when I attempt to pass a delegate to the method. I imagine the problem with my code lies in the way I've setup my delegate, but I can't seem to figure it out, even after searching around on google.

I'm creating my delegate like so:

```
public delegate void GetLatencyDelegate(Server server);
```

I'm attempting to loop through a list of servers and run the servers GetLatency method. Each time I loop through to a new server, a new thread should be ran from the pool to run the GetLatency method. The idea is that this should speed up the process. My code for this is the following:

```
            ThreadPool.SetMaxThreads(50, 50);

            foreach (Server server in serverList)
            {
                GetLatencyDelegate gld = new GetLatencyDelegate(server.GetLatency);
                ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(new WaitCallback(gld));

            }
```

However, I get two errors. One being:

> "No overload for 'GetLatencyDelegate' matches delegate
>   'System.Threading.WaitCallback'

The other being:

> 'No overload for 'GetLatency' matches delegate
>   'Program.GetLatencyDelegate'

Comment: Try out `ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem((p) => new WaitCallback(gld));`

Comment: Well for one is the server.GetLatency of the same signature as void GetLatencyDelegate(Server server) because if it is not then that is not going to work. 2 when you call the delegate , you are not passing in an arguement into the threadpool. ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(new WaitCallback(ThreadProc), Server);

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first error occurs because the signature for [`WaitCallback`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.waitcallback.aspx) is not the same as the signature for `GetLatencyDelegate`. The two should be identical.

The second error occurs because `Server.GetLatency` also does not have a signature compatible with `GetLatencyDelegate`: the former accepts no parameters, while the latter expects the `Server` instance to be passed in.

In fact there is absolutely no need to define `GetLatencyDelegate` in the first place. You can simply provide a lambda with a signature compatible with `WaitCallback`:

```
foreach (Server server in serverList)
{
    ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(srv => ((Server)srv).GetLatency(), server);
}
```

Comment: According to his delegate definition the `GetLatency` method takes a `Server` parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

```
ThreadPool.SetMaxThreads(50, 50);

foreach (Server server in serverList)
{
    ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(state => 
    {
        var srv = ((Server)state);
        srv.GetLatency(srv);
    }, server);
}
```